# Piecewise smooth homotopy

Tags: differential-topology, vector-analysis

Let $M$ be a simply connected smooth manifold ($M=R^3$ is enough for my purposes).

Then, the following Proposition 1 is obvious.

> **Proposition 1**
> For all  piecewise smooth loop, $c[0,1]\to M$, there is $H$ such
> that;
>   (1) $H:I\to M$ is a continuous mapping, Here $I:=[0,1]\times[0,1]$ 
>   (2) For all t,s  ($0\le t\le 1$, $0\le t\le 1$)
>       $H(t,0) =c(t)$
>       $H(0,s) = H(1,s)$
>       $H(t,1) =c(0)$

∵It is just a paraphrase of the definition of a simply connected space.■

And if there is **piecewise smooth $H$**, then, for all smooth one-form $\omega$ ($\omega$ is a differential 1-form on M), we can define $H^{*}\omega$ (Here, $H^{*}\omega$ is a pullback of the $\omega$ ) and when we integrate $d{H}^{*}\omega$ over the interval $I:=[0,1]\times[0,1]$  and integrate $H^{*}\omega$ over the $\partial I$,  we can obtain following proposition:

> **Proposition 2**
> Let $\omega$ be  a  smooth One-form on $M$, $d\omega = 0$, and, $c:[0,1]\to M$ be a piecewise smooth loop on M, then,
>       ${\oint}_{c} \omega = 0$

However,  it is not obvious to me that, Can it happen that "there is the only $H$ that is not piecewise smooth but continuous ?"

> **My Doubt**: 
> Whether the following  is correct ?:
> For all  piecewise smooth loop, $c[0,1]\to M$, there is $H$ such
> that;
>   (1) $H:I\to M$ is a piecewise smooth mapping, (Here $I:=[0,1]\times[0,1]$ )
>   (2) For all t,s  ($0\le t\le 1$, $0\le t\le 1$)
>       $H(t,0) =c(t)$
>       $H(0,s) = H(1,s)$
>       $H(t,1) =c(0)$

If correct, please give proof or site reference literature.
If wrong, please tell me a counterexample and tell me "how to justify the proposition 2.""

> Edit: Maybe one can prove it using this [book](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=eqfgZtjQceYC&pg=PA258&lpg=PA258&dq=smooth+homotopy&source=bl&ots=x_82Cgz3G5&sig=ACfU3U0lul0yEoZ1PBRHCq6nWIxB6mi_EQ&hl=ja&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwizkIbG96fkAhWGHXAKHfjoC2AQ6AEwCHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=smooth%20homotopy&f=false) ...
> --Added on September 25, 2019.

Comment: It is almost the same question as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1028457/smooth-homotopy#:~:text=The%20Whitney%20Approximation%20Theorem%20says,wherever%20it%20is%20already%20smooth.

Comment: The trick is to construct first a piecewise-smooth homotopy to a smooth loop. This can be even done without changing the image of the original loop.